# Using BigInt - Rails 5.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently generated migrations to migrate my foreign keys to big ints on our Rails application, but I receive the following error when loading the application.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

Any ideas as to why I'm getting this error? I was following this blog post about the new Rails convention - http://www.mccartie.com/2016/12/05/rails-5.1.html

Sample migration:

```
class ChangePrimaryKeyToBigintOnOrganizations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_column :organizations, :id, :bigint
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you really will need [bigint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-numeric.html)? It's when you need more than 2B rows.

Answer (score 1):

The column's auto_increment attribute isn't preserved when changing the column type so you'll need to do it yourself:

```
change_column :organizations, :id, :bigint, auto_increment: true
```